# Does anyone know where i can find secret_twitter module for python 2.7?

Tags: python, twitter

I ran into some trouble while importing consumer_keys,consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret from secret_twitter while using the TwitterAPI.

The error message shows that I dont have any module named secret_twitter and I couldn't find any path or way to download secret_twitter.

So any help on the same would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip freeze` to know what python-twitter version you have, it will tell us more ways to help you.

Also, there're lot of "secret" options with this package:

```
pip install twitter_bot_utils
```